# How can I restrict network access to Firefox when using a certain SSID in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, 3g

I often share Internet access from my mobile (3G) to my computer with WiFi (using a certain SSID "MyMobile").

Unfortunately, I have some programs that download updates, including my Windows 7 OS, since they don't understand that I have a very limited download speed.

Is there a way to restrict network access so that only Firefox can access the Internet when using a certain SSID?

Edit: When connecting to my default WiFi (with another SSID "SpeedInternet"), I would like all programs to automatically have access to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to automatically restrict network access so that only
>   Firefox can access Internet?

Yes there is. Go to Control-Panel->Firewall->Advanced Settings. Then click on outbound rules to control what programs and services can access your network. By default, all outgoing connections will be allowed except those mentioned in the outbound rules. However, you can create your new rule stating that only Firefox should be allowed network access.

Comment: Thank you! I have now updated the question. When connecting to my default WiFi (with another SSID "SpeedInternet"), I would like all programs to automatically have access to Internet.